# Unable to get Image file URL from eclipse plugin project Bundle

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to get image from a bundle in eclipse plugin project. But it always return null. Please find the project structure below. I want to get the URL of an image "icon_4.png" which is under "images/EmailTemplatesOutput/assets/icon_4.png". I have tried different ways. But it returns null.

Project Structure is :
[image]

```
            String path = "icon_4.png";
            Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("BulkDemo");
            URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new org.eclipse.core.runtime.Path(path), null);
            ImageDescriptor imageDesc = ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(url);
            Image image = imageDesc.createImage();
```

Comment: Which statement returns null? Which different ways have you tried? Was one of them with a path of `images/EmailTemplatesOutput/assets/icon_4.png`?

Comment: FileLocator.find(bundle, new org.eclipse.core.runtime.Path(path), null); this statement returns null.Yes. "images/EmailTemplatesOutput/assets/icon_4.png" returns null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put the 'images' directory in the 'src' folder, put it at the top level of the project (like 'bin' and 'META-INF'). Make sure you update the 'build.properties' to include the images folder in the build.

The path for the image is relative to the plug-in root so it will be `images/EmailTemplatesOutput/assests/icon_4.png` (assuming you move the images directory).

The URL returned by `FileLocator.find` uses an Eclipse only scheme so can only be used by Eclipse APIs. You can convert the URL to a normal file URL by adding:

```
URL fileURL = FileLocator.toFileURL(url);
```

This may cause Eclipse to unpack your plug-in to a temporary location to access the files.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. But how to use that path in image tag in src attribute? I have to give like <img src="" alt="Images" width="42" height="42"></img>

Comment: None of this is available to a web server if you are talking about an actual web page or is this a HTML page in the SWT browser?

Comment: Added information about `toFileURL` which you can use for a SWT Browser page.

Comment: It is org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser. I have set that html content inside that browser. The html contains img tag and i am not able to resolve that img location.